# VB6 usercontrol Raise Event, how to catch the event in VBSCRIPT?

Tags: events, user-controls, vb6, vbscript, activex

I am trying to catch an event in the VBSCRIPT of an html page but I can't make it work. I must have missed a step.

This is the code of my usercontrol (VB6):

```
Public Event sendText(ByVal Text As String)

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    RaiseEvent sendText(Text1.Text)
End Sub
```

And this is the code of my web page (HTML):

```
<form>

<OBJECT name="ActiveX" id="ActiveX" classid="clsid:..."></OBJECT>
<script language="VBScript">

Sub ActiveX_sendText(Text)
 Msgbox("aaa" & Text)
End Sub

</script>
</form>
```

The Event is raised in the user control when clicking the Command1 button, but I never get into the VBSCRIPT function.

I am using IE8/IE8 Standard.

Any clue?

Comment: The first thing that strikes me is to use `ByVal` in your script event handler's parameter list to match the signature of the event.

Comment: I've changed the VBSCRIPT signature of the method to match the one defined in the usercontrol (ByVal Text As String) but it did not solve the issue :+|

Comment: Well there is no `As String` in VBScript, so that won't help.  You could try changing the VB6 UserControl to use `As Variant` but I doubt that why it isn't working.

Comment: My mistake, first time I am using Vbscript.
Here is the full test case: http://youtu.be/rm1HSPDWtqg

Comment: Well it could even be because you define the script after you define the object.  HTML gets parsed and processed sequentially, so perhaps the event binding isn't taking place.  I find it much cleaner to put nearly all script in the `head` instead of the `body` of a page anyway.

Comment: I've tried (and I usually do) to put the script block in the head section but still the event binding isn't taking place.
Vbscript works because if I put a simple Msgbox "test" above the function it will display the VB message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem in the configuration of security rules in Internet Explorer. After enabling unsigned ActiveX, the issue was solved.